# Problem stopping/starting MySQL Workbench

Tags: database-connection, mysql-workbench

I've installed the MySQL workbench version 5.2.34 and having problems creating a local connection.  I'm getting an error saying "Can't Connect to MySQL Server on 127.0.0.1'(10061)" when i try connecting to Localhost on Port 3306. I tried restarting the service but i don't have the option to stop/start/pause or resume using Windows 7. The status is just set to "starting". I also tried "net stop mysql" from the command line in DOS but get the following error: "The service is starting or stopping.  Please try again later"

Does anyone know if this is another bug in the Workbench or is there a quick solution to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restart mysql from services. Also, check error log (by default, on Windows 7 machine it's under `...ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server [version]\data`

Comment: Hi, i can't restart mysql from services as its not giving me the option to stop it. It's like its looping or something. Whats the name of the error log under the data folder?

Comment: Also, if you cannot stop the service normally, you always have an option to kill the process from task manager(don't forget to click on `Show processes from all users`)

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for that, i didn't see the mysqld.exe process as i hadn't got the show processes from all users box ticked under the processes tab.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a problem with MySQL itself starting up. You may have to kill the `mysqld` process if nothing else gets it into a started or stopped state, and then investigate the `.err` logs in your data directory.

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses the ***window's mysql installer*** which you have used to install your MySQL.

Even though this post is very old, I have wasted around 2 hours and hence want to post this so that it can save someone else's time.

I have tried every other way of restartring the service, but mysql service just wont start.

1. Start your windows mysql installer. For me it was "mysql-installer-community-8.0.20.0"
2. Then remove/uninstall the SQL Server and remove all configurations
3. Manually delete the SQL Server folder from "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0."
4. Start your mysql installer again and install the SQL Server again
5. You can check now that the MySqL Server has started.